# Operators as complex numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, complex-numbers

I recently came across a paper where the following manipulation had been done after  writing *considering
Heisenberg Operators as complex numbers*

$$\delta a^\dagger*a_s=a_s*\delta a^\dagger$$

(where $a$ and $a^\dagger$ represent usual annihilation and creation operators and $a_s$ is for steady state in the sense that $a^\dagger_s a_s$=corresponds to number operator in steady state)

I need to know how this manipulation is done? In essence how are these operators considered as complex numbers as mentioned above? Since this would justify the manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bosonic creation operators can be considered as complex numbers as in the fact that they commute $$[a, a^\dagger] = 0$$ where you have to consider that $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are two different complex numbers. This in turns implies your equality since, given two bosonic creation operators $a_s$ and $\delta a$, you have $$[a_s,\delta a] = 0\implies a_s\delta a = \delta aa_s$$

This consideration gives us the possibility to regard fermionic creation and annihilation operators as [Grassmann numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number), instead of complex ones. Two Grassmann numbers $\theta, \bar{\theta}$, instead of commuting they anti-commute $$\{\theta, \bar\theta\}=0$$ which would make your equality take a minus sign whenever you interchange two creation or annihilation operators.

Comment: Wait, isn’t $[a_i,a^{\dagger}_j]=\delta_{ij}$ for bosons?

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Yes, the QM commutator rule wants $[a,a^\dagger] = \hbar$ but whenever we introduce the concept of path integral, in the sum over paths $a(t)$ and $a^\dagger(t)$ are treated as functions with numerical values, i.e. as quantities which commute. Therefore, it is as if a classical limit $\hbar\to0$ is taken, in which $[a, a^\dagger]=0$

Comment: These operators indeed are related to bosons (photons) where $a^\dagger a$=number of photons entering a cavity. But previously the author has mentioned $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ but shouldn't it be zero as you mentioned?

Comment: Is it that what @Superfast Jellyfish mentioned of it being a kronecker delta  more relevant here?

Comment: Also @David could you elaborate a little more when you say that the commutator limit tends to zero. That would be helpful for understanding where the author has considered their commutator as a kronecker and where as zero (taking the classical limit).

Comment: It's $[a, a^\dagger]=1$ in natural units, whenever you go back to normal units you have to put back the $\hbar$. Whenever working in the quantum regime, so operators, you need to use the canonical commutator relation $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$. But whenever you're doing QFT calculations in the path integral quantisation, the creation and annihilation operator are regarded as classical fields, and so the commuting (or anticommuting for fermion fields) quantities.